# scala project Compile error with IntelliJ community edition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, build

I am having the following build error when building a scala project using IntelliJ (community edition):

Error:(42, 609) not found: value collect_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collect_list` is a *spark* function so you need to `import` *spark function library* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```